# Using cd command with fork in c

Tags: c, linux, directory, fork, chdir

Is it possible to change around directories using the fork command? Without going too much into my code I have the following:

```
childpid = fork();

if (childpid >= 0)
{
    if (childpid == 0)
    {   
        ret = execvp(argv[0],argv);
        exit(ret);    
    } else {

          waitpid(childpid,&status,0);
          ret = WEXITSTATUS(status);
    }
}
```

The above works fine when I'm entering basic command like `ls`, `pwd`, etc.. Is it possible to implement a way to use the cd function? I can type the command `cd ..` but it doesn't do anything.

For example if my program is in `/Users/username/Desktop/` I would like to use commands such as `cd ..` to go into `/Users/username/` or be able to go straight into `/Users`

I've seen some stuff about `chdir` but I'm not sure exactly how it works/how to use it.

Comment: The current directory is specific to each process. So your shell process is in /Users/username/Desktop, and you type `cd ..`, and that creates a new process, and the new process changes to /Users/username, but the shell process doesn't because it's a different process from the one that changed directory.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentionned [`chdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chdir) is the best way to change the working directory of the current process, a shell command `cd` would only change the working directory of of the process running the command ( and not the parent process ) as `fork` would create a new process.

for chdir usage you could try :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    char cwd[4096];
    fputs(getcwd(cwd,4096),stdout); // will print the current working directory
    fputs("\n",stdout); 
    chdir("/"); // change directory
    fputs(getcwd(cwd,4096),stdout); // print new working directory
    fputs("\n",stdout);
}
```